# Why jQuery rounds value?

Tags: jquery, spring-web

Using ajax i request a authenticationID like this:
[image]

---

This is **wrong** because the real HTTP-Transfer is this:

[image]

(By the way: response-type is "application/json;charset=UTF-8")

I see a clash between

```
-1369082024195183657 and 
-1369082024195183600
```

How to prevent the rounding or is it a bug?

Comment: I didn't count the digits, because you only provide them as image. But the maximum integer in js is `+/-9007199254740991`, everything lager then that has floating point precision. [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179) If you want to have a higher precision you need to use a decimal/bignumber library.

Comment: You can try to use float. It looks big.

Comment: But isn't HTTP response always a string? It shouldn't be prone to integer limitations unless jQuery tries too hard and decides to convert the response to a number under the hood.

Comment: @pawel if it is send as JSON response, then it is number, because there are no quotes. If it is send as plain text is should stay a string.

Comment: @t.niese but it doesn't look like JSON at all, see the screenshot of "response" tab: there's a single negative number, not a key/value pair wrapped in curly braces.

Comment: @pawel  JSON does not need _curly braces_ : `JSON.stringify(42);` results in  `42`.  _curly braces_ are only there if you want to represent an object with properties, so `true`, `false`,  `42` and `"string"`  are all valid JSON data.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate in my opinion. The question is about jquery and ajax treating string data as integer data. The question it's marked as a duplicate of is simply about jacascript's limits. The question here can be solved by managing to send the data as a string.

Comment: @ChrisLear Will it help to add the java-code?

Comment: Of course it's not a duplicate. The answer would be: set the `dataType` property in your `$.ajax` method to `text` so jQuery doesn't guess it's JSON and doesn't convert to int. i.e. `$.ajax({ dataType : "text", url : "..." })`

Comment: @pawel has an answer looks that right to me

Comment: And now a possibly valuable answer to a legitimate question will get buried in the comments section because someone went trigger happy without bothering to read and understand the problem ;)

Comment: I'd like to re-open this question, but I don't think I can even vote to do that. Pity.

Comment: Question is now reopened. Go ahead, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a bug. The Server returns illegal JSON! Created report: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/291

Answer (score 3):

jQuery tries to parse the HTTP response as integer based on the JSON content-type.

```
> JSON.parse("-1369082024195183657")
-1369082024195183600
```

You can override it by telling jQuery you expect a string by setting the `dataType` property in `$.ajax` configuration:

```
$.ajax({ 
   dataType : "text", 
   url : "rest/Registration",
   success : function(data){
       // data should be "-1369082024195183657"
   }
})
```

I guess you don't need to do any arithmetic operations on an authenticationID token, so you can just keep it as a string.